# Worklight 6.2 upgrade to Mobilefirst 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

After upgrading from Worklight 6.2 to Mobilefirst 6.3 on an AIX server using websphere 8.5 the operations console is throwing a server error. Everything appears to startup but we are not able to login. What is odd is that we are not seeing anything jumping out at us in the logs. I've seen a few posts regarding this upgrade but was wondering if anyone had any issues specific to 6.2 to 6.3 and possibly jndi?

Thanks
Frank

Comment: Please add the *server error* you are seeing.

Comment: After several attempts we elected to do a MobileFirst 6.3 fresh install. We did have a few issues related to ssl. I added the following and things work now:

Comment: ibm.worklight.admin.ui.cors.strictssl=false

Comment: @Frank, please write it as a detailed answer and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Frank disappeared. From the comments:

> After several attempts we elected to do a MobileFirst 6.3 fresh
>   install. We did have a few issues related to ssl. I added the
>   following to server.xml and things work now:
>   `ibm.worklight.admin.ui.cors.strictssl=false`

Answer (score 0):

as I said after trying several things posted on the forum for version 6.2 with no success we did a fresh 6.3 install and applied the ifix:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI30521

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI31900

The install worked without issue after that. There is no more details other then that. Thanks for your assistance.

Frank